Why are くる and する not exceptions for the conditional ば?
In modern Japanese, the 仮定形 of くる and する follow standard patterns: すれ and くれ. How come? Is it an accident? Is it linked to their 已然形? If so, was it already regular in classical Japanese (and maybe older)?

Verbs する (OJ: su) and 来{く}る (OJ: ku) are actually mostly regular (more regular in Old and Middle Japanese than in Modern Japanese).
Their stems (not to be confused with 連用形 or any other form) are se- (possibly from older sə-) and ko- (possibly kə- in Old Japanese) (the latter verb is the only verb in Japanese with stem ending with vowel o or ə).
Their 連用形 are formed with deletion of stem-final vowel and preservation of vowel of suffix -i (in contrast to regular weak vowel-stem (二段活用) verbs):
se- + -i → si (し)
kə- + -i → ki (来{き})
Their 終止形, 連体形, 已然形 are formed in the same way as for regular weak vowel-stem (二段活用) verbs.
已然形:
se- + -ure → sure (すれ)
kə- + -ure → kure (来{く}れ)
Old Japanese and Middle Japanese have 2 suffixes ending with ᵐba:

-(a)ᵐba (called Conditional Converb -aᵐba ~ -ᵐba by Alexander Vovin)
About meanings of this suffix, Alexander Vovin (2020, "A Descriptive and Comparative Grammar of Western Old Japanese", page 655) wrote:

In contrast to Middle Japanese, where the conditional converb introduces only irrealis and realis conditional clauses (Vovin 2003: 252), in Western Old Japanese -aᵐba ~ -ᵐba also introduces a temporal connection, although it occurs only if there is a following tentative -(a)m- or negative tentative -aⁿzi in a sentence.

se- + -(a)ᵐba → seᵐba (せば)
kə- + -(a)ᵐba → kəᵐba → koᵐba (来{こ}ば)

已然形 + -ᵐba (called Conjunctive Converb -ᵐba by Alexander Vovin)
About meanings of this suffix, Alexander Vovin (2020, "A Descriptive and Comparative Grammar of Western Old Japanese", pages 664-665) wrote:

In traditional grammar -ᵐba is considered to have three meanings: (1) reason; (2) realis condition; (3) temporal connection of two actions (‘when X, then Y’) (Yamada 1954: 480–482). However, in Western Old Japanese the conjunctive converb -ᵐba does not indicate the realis condition unless it is a temporal condition. I therefore view this temporal condition as a particular case of the temporal connection function. General conditions are expressed by the conditional converb -aᵐba ~ -ᵐba or by other means, such as a combination of the subordinative converb -te or the negative converb -aⁿz-u with the following topic particle pa.

sure + -ᵐba → sureᵐba (すれば)
kure + -ᵐba → kureᵐba (来{く}れば)
In Modern Japanese, voiced obstruents lost prenasalization (/ᵐb/ → /b/, /ⁿz/ → /z/ etc.), and 已然形 + -ba has taken over function of suffix -(a)ba. (Some remnants of suffix -(a)ba remain in words such as ならば and さらば.)



This reminds me of how it's the plain form of 良い that's the exception.

Notably, all of the man'yōgana for /ko₂/ listed in the Wikipedia page except for 木 (where /ko₂/ is the kun'yomi) use Chinese characters where the reconstructed Middle Chinese pronunciations include a palatal glide at the onset, often /-ie-/ or /-iə-/.  This raises interesting questions about whether the root form of the verb 来 was /kə/, or perhaps something else.

Separately, I recall reading years ago that the Old Japanese -aba ending meant "if", while the -eba ending meant "because". Viewed through the lens of the names for the conjugation stems, these could be parsed as the "irrealis" /-a/ stem + topic / nominalization particle は = "it hasn't happened, but if it did ...", while the "realis" /-e/ stem + topic / nominalization particle は = "it has happened, and so ...".

@EiríkrÚtlendi Would you happen to have any sort of a source on this, it sounds fascinating and I'd love to read more about it.

@Saegusa, there's a pretty comprehensive entry about ば and it's syntax and meaning in the 日本国語大辞典【にほんこくごだいじてん】 (NKD) entry here at Kotobank. I don't see anything in that entry about ば coming from topic particle は; I'll do some digging later.

Frellesvig (2010, "A History of the Japanese Language", page 121) speculated that "-(a)ba conditional < *-amu-pa" and that this *-amu was from the conjectural suffix. While Vovin (2020, page 663) speculated "Therefore, we can probably reconstruct the PJ conditional suffix *-anpa, although it is quite likely that originally it was some kind of a bound noun.".
